# How do I put a QComboBox inside QColumnView

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

**Scenario:** I need to put a combo box inside the 4th column in qcolumnview, so the user can choose ON or OFF.

**Description:** In the future this will be saved as an XML file, so the user can select the parameter and generate a custom XML file.
Can someone tell me how do I do that?

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class xml_creator(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(xml_creator, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        column_view = QtGui.QColumnView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(column_view)

        m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        column_view.setModel(m_model)
        column_view.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        self.test_variables = {}
        self.test_variables['OPTION_1'] = ['OFF', 'ON']
        self.test_variables['OPTION_2'] = ['OFF', 'ON']

        self.iq_xml = {}
        self.iq_xml['TEST_1'] = {}
        self.iq_xml['TEST_1']['Test_case_1'] = self.test_variables

        for x in self.iq_xml:

            if not self.iq_xml[x]:
                continue
            parent = QtGui.QStandardItem(x)
            parent.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable)

            for y in self.iq_xml[x]:
                if not self.iq_xml[x][y]:
                    continue
                child0 = QtGui.QStandardItem(y)
                child0.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                parent.appendRow(child0)


                for z in self.iq_xml[x][y]:
                    if not self.iq_xml[x][y][z]:
                        continue

                    grand_child = QtGui.QStandardItem(z)
                    grand_child.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                    child0.appendRow(grand_child)

                    value = self.iq_xml[x][y][z]
                    grand_grand_child = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(value))
                    grand_grand_child.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
                    grand_child.appendRow(grand_grand_child)

            column_view.model().appendRow(parent)

        column_view.setColumnWidths([200, 200, 200, 100])

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 1000, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('IQ XML Creator')
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = xml_creator()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be complete.  Can you create a working example (and strip out some of the unnecessary parts) so we can focus on the question.

Comment: I completed the code. Do you have any idea how I can display the  ['OFF', 'ON'] as a combo box?

Comment: I figured you could do this with an `ItemDelegate` but I had a go and couldn't get it to work, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a solution for that but I found a workaround, so I'm posting hoping to help who has the same problem as me.

Once I couldnt put the combobox in the QColumnView as I was trying, my workaround was to create a table filled with the comboboxes I wanted, and then setting this QTable as the preview widget in QColumnView.